What was the horror movie in which a man must stay all night in a "haunted" house?
There is an old movie (likely well before 1975) in which the plot involves a man who must survive one night in a "haunted" house.  He experiences a very strange night indeed.  At the end of the film, he leaves the house at dawn,  successfully surviving the night.  But as he leaves the property, an iron gate closes behind him and a bent spike on the gate impales him.  He dies.
What is the title of this film, what year was it released, and who was its lead actor?

No...I am looking for this movie, too. I remember it from my childhood...could swear the lead character wad William Shatner.

Sounds like Danza Macabra (AKA Castle of Blood) from 1964:

A writer accepts a bet [From Edgar Allan Poe!] that he cannot spend the night alone in a haunted castle on All Soul's Eve. Once night falls at the castle, several who had been murdered therein return to life, reliving their deaths and seeking to kill the writer for his blood in a vain attempt to stay alive beyond that one night. Barbara Steele, as one of the living dead, tries to aid his escape from the castle.

And in the end:

Being outside the castle may have skeletonized Steele but it doesn't prevent the other spirits from following the reporter and slamming the gate shut behind him, impaling him on one of its spikes. Their voices keep repeating, "We need your blood. Now you are one of us." 

Here's the trailer:



